# efibootmgr & The rEFInd Boot Manager: unknown boot sequence w/ chinese letters

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, refind, chinese, efibootmgr

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0080
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* 綋瑰污萏«¸
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

I'm trying to configure Ubuntu correctly; one of my headaches is that the rEFInd boot menus no longer appears. When I checked out the boot sequence, Boot0002 was unknown to me and confusing for me. Thoughts on a path forward?

ANY idea on BOOT0002 ? Google has zero results!

My current issues are: no sound, no bluetooth, mouse works only on 75% of boot ups, no rEFInd boot menu.

My machine: (MBP 13"2016)
My OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with refind disapppearing. Unfortunately I don't know what could be causing your lack of sound and Bluetooth.

For refind, what worked for me was removing the Chinese character boot entry and manually re-adding refind as a boot entry.

You can adapt the commands below:

```
efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries.

sudo efibootmgr -b 0002 -B
#remove all of the Chinese character boot options. For you the boot number appears to be 0002.

sudo nautilus /boot/efi
#this helped me determine the file path for refind on my system. In my case it was /boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi

df -h
#view all of your system partitions. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi

sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L refind -l /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi
#you can type "man efibootmgr" for more information. You need to determine which partition on your system corresponds to /boot/efi and put the number of that partition after the -p option.

efibootmgr -v
#at this point, check the numbers of the boot entries. In my case refind was 0000 and ubuntu was 0001.

sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0001
```

For more information, see:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples